# FFMPEG, resize, watermark and compress a video

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, subtitles, matroska, watermark

I can't quite combine a couple of commands in FFMPEG.
I'm trying to

1. Burn in an external subtitle file
2. map all other streams since the file contains many audio and subtitle tracks i don't wish to alter.
3. Compress the video to x265 crf 32
4. Change resolution to 1280*720

I tried this it does everything except for scaling to 720p:

```
_i input.mkv -filter:v scale=1280*720 -map 0 -vf subtitles=individual.ass -c copy -c:vlibx265 -crf 32 output.mkv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain together simple linear (1-in/1-out) filters with a comma, and use `-filter_complex` so you can more easily map the desired streams.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0]scale=1280:720,subtitles=individual.ass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy -c:v libx265 -crf 32 output.mkv
```

Comment: Trying to compose commands to scale/compress video + adding watermak to the right top of the video. "-i", trimmedVideoOutputPath,
           /* "-i", getLogoImagePath(),
            "-filter_complex", "overlay=20:20",*/ How to add the logo?
            "-vf",
            "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2",
            "-vcodec", "libx264",
            "-crf", "30",
            "-preset", "ultrafast",
            "-c:a", "copy", convertedVideoOutputPath

Comment: @NatanRubinstein "-i", trimmedVideoOutputPath, /* "-i", getLogoImagePath(), "-filter_complex", "overlay=20:20,scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-crf", "30", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-c:a", "copy", convertedVideoOutputPath

Comment: thank you so much. it's working! )